# XML parsing Using TBXML need to handle Network Time out in IOS?

Tags: ios, xml, xml-parsing, tbxml

Currently parsing remote content straightly using TBXML by initwithURL method. But while parsing data if network time out occurs parsing stopped intermediately. Don`t know how to handle that scenario , at the same time no delegate will call.

If any one know the solution, please help me out.

Note : XML content is very large about half million of data , parsing is also happen in background thread.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `NSURLConnection` to download xml data and then use

```
TBXML * tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithXMLData:myXMLData] retain];
```

Comment: But for downloading data it will take long time around 15min user have to wait, but the way i use its begin the download once it got the responses.

Comment: TBXL first downloads the file then starts the processing. What way are you doing ?

Comment: Instead of downloading entire content and start parsing, i need to parse where it hits the URL and corresponding root element of XML.